# Failed to load native library

Tags: android, android-ndk, cardio

Failed to load native library when i work with ndk functions in android studio. so please help me i am new for doing this and please correct me if wrong any where. Actually i was doing some scanning document using cardio sdk.
Basically i want  to scan any document  like cardio but i want to scan boundary not text or number only boundary of documents. if you have any other solution then please suggest me.

```
This is my activity code.
 if (nUseNeon()) {
                System.loadLibrary("cardioRecognizer");
                Log.i(Util.PUBLIC_LOG_TAG, "Loaded card.io NEON library");
            }
This is my error in my log cat.

Failed to load native library: JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app/com.surfaceview2-1/lib/arm/libcardioRecognizer.so"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check that:

1) you have the libcardioRecognizer.so library in the folder: `app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi` of your Android Studio project

2) the library is compatibile with the architecture of the device you're using. If not, you can compile it and place in the folder:

```
app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a (for arm-v7 architecture)
app/src/main/jniLibs/x86 (for x86 architecture)
```

Comment: i have already placed libcardioRecognizer.so in(jniLibs/armeabi-v7a)